# Extract all the text from xml data with python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm new to xml data processing. I want to extract the text data in the following xml file:

```
<data>
    <p>12345<strong>45667</strong>abcde</p>
</data>
```

so that expected result is:
 `['12345','45667', 'abcde']` Currently I have tried:

```
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
data = tree.getiterator()
text = [data[i].text for i in range(0, len(data))]
```

But the result only shows  `['12345','45667']` .  `'abcde'` is missing. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) :

```
import lxml.etree as etree

string = '''
<data>
    <p>12345<strong>45667</strong>abcde</p>
</data>
'''

tree = etree.fromstring(string)

print(tree.xpath('//p//text()'))
```

The Xpath expression means: "select all **p** elements wich containing **text** recursively"

#### OUTPUT:

```
['12345', '45667', 'abcde']
```

Comment: Are you sure the OP is using `lxml`? Also, what about adding some explanation?

Comment: OP calls `ET.parse` which is from lxml as etree in their documentation from http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Comment: @Camron_Godbout doesn't make a difference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.parse

Answer (score 2):

`getiterator()` (or it's replacement [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter)) iterates over child tags/elements, while `abcde` is a text node, a [`tail`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) of the `strong` tag.

You can use [`itertext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext) method:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
print list(tree.find('p').itertext())
```

Prints:

```
['12345', '45667', 'abcde']
```